# Circle as a background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I draw a circle as decoration in the background on my scaffold, so it's behind all the elements in the scaffold. Is it possible or do I need to use a different layout? 
I've tried to draw it but every time its stays on top of everything else, not in the background.

[image: This is the design]

Comment: You can use a `CustomClipper` with  the container. Watch this video the author does the same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeMJz3EcBgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you did draw the Circle no?, if you need to put on bottom of other elements you can use Stack:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    BottomElementFirst(),
    MiddleElementSecond(),
    TopElementLast(),
  ],
)
```

Hope it helps!